# Java Apache HTTP Client

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

First question asked on Stack Overflow, so please be gentle. I have been practicing my Java and I am trying out the HTTP Client by Apache. I am getting a status code of 200 when connecting to an xbox api. Which to me means I passed the key correctly to the header and I should now be able to pull my profile from different endpoints.

My question is what do I call next after response.getEntity()? I have been trying to just print the data to the console as is to ensure what I was getting back is what I wanted. However, I keep getting a null pointer exception which I think is telling there is nothing in the body? The end result would be to then take the json to java object. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks

public static void main(String[] args)  {

```
    HttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
            HttpStatus.SC_OK,
            "OK");

    HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().build();
    HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()
            .setUri(url)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, apiKey)
            .build();
    try {
        client.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        entity.getContent();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Something like `response =  client.execute(request);`?

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the method

```
 HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request)
    throws IOException, ClientProtocolException;
```

So in essence you should get the response from the called method.

Change just one line of your code

```
response=client.execute(request);
```

This should populate the response and always check for null before calling any method of response.
Something like this

```
if(response!=null && response.getEntity()!=null) {
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
}
```

Comment: So with the above code added I now get a 401 response code. Why wouldn't it pass the authentication a return 200 before and now change? One last favor did I set the header parameter correctly for X-Auth by using the             .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, apiKey).

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to issue a curl command and see what is getting returned as the response...

Answer (score 0):

Yea with the response of 401 I figured by header wasn't set correctly. I ended up changing the header code with:

.setHeader("X-AUTH", apiKey)

Authorization is not the same as X-Auth. I didn't know I could just type it in as a string. Thank you all for guiding me into the right direction.